# How to run the DistributedLanczosSolver on mahout

Tags: mahout

I am trying to run the Lanczos Example of mahout.
I am having trouble finding the input file. and what should be the format of input file.

I have used the commands to convert the .txt file into sequence File format by running:

```
bin/mahout seqdirectory -i input.txt -o outseq -c UTF-8
bin/mahout seq2sparse -i outseq -o ttseq

bin/hadoop jar mahout-examples-0.9-SNAPSHOT-job.jar org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.decomposer.DistributedLanczosSolver --input /user/hduser/outputseq --output /out1 --numCols 2 --numRows 4 --cleansvd "true" --rank 5

14/03/20 13:36:12 INFO lanczos.LanczosSolver: Finding 5 singular vectors of matrix with 4 rows, via Lanczos
14/03/20 13:36:13 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 7
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/ttseq/df-count/data
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.DistributedRowMatrix.timesSquared(DistributedRowMatrix.java:245)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.decomposer.lanczos.LanczosSolver.solve(LanczosSolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.decomposer.DistributedLanczosSolver.run(DistributedLanczosSolver.java:200)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.decomposer.DistributedLanczosSolver.run(DistributedLanczosSolver.java:152)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.decomposer.DistributedLanczosSolver.run(DistributedLanczosSolver.java:111)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.decomposer.DistributedLanczosSolver$DistributedLanczosSolverJob.run(DistributedLanczosSolver.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.decomposer.DistributedLanczosSolver.main(DistributedLanczosSolver.java:289)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/ttseq/df-count/data
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:457)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:781)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1249)
    at org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.DistributedRowMatrix.timesSquared(DistributedRowMatrix.java:237)
    ... 13 more
```

Any idea please?

Comment: I am also seeing the same error. However, I am running mahout version 0.7: `mahout seq2sparse -i /output-seq2sparse -o /output-seq2sparse-normalized -ow -a org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer -chunk 200 -wt tfidf -s 5 -md 3 -x 90 -ng 2  -ml 50 -seq -n 2 -nr 5`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are doing **input.txt** -> **outseq** -> **ttseq**.

You are using **outputseq** (but not **outseq**) as input to generate **out1**.

And you are getting error with **ttseq**. That is strange? Perhaps you are missing some step in your post.

---

For me:

This **PASSES**: **text-files** -> **output-seqdir** -> **output-seq2sparse-normalized**

This **FAILS**: **text-files** -> **output-seqdir** -> **output-seq2sparse** -> **output-seq2sparse-normalized**

More details.

I am seeing this error in a different situation:

Create sequence files

```
$ mahout seqdirectory -i /data/lda/text-files/ -o /data/lda/output-seqdir -c UTF-8
Running on hadoop, using ....hadoop-1.1.1/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: ....mahout-distribution-0.7/mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar
14/03/24 20:47:25 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--charset=[UTF-8], --chunkSize=[64], --endPhase=[2147483647], --fileFilterClass=[org.apache.mahout.text.PrefixAdditionFilter], --input=[/data/lda/ohsumed_full_txt/ohsumed_full_txt/], --keyPrefix=[], --output=[/data/lda/output], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
14/03/24 20:57:20 INFO driver.MahoutDriver: Program took 594764 ms (Minutes: 9.912733333333334)
```

Convert sequence files to sparse vectors. Use TFIDF by default.

```
$ mahout seq2sparse -i /data/lda/output-seqdir -o /data/lda/output-seq2sparse/ -ow
Running on hadoop, using ....hadoop-1.1.1/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: ....mahout-distribution-0.7/mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar
14/03/24 21:00:08 INFO vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles: Maximum n-gram size is: 1
14/03/24 21:00:09 INFO vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles: Minimum LLR value: 1.0
14/03/24 21:00:09 INFO vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles: Number of reduce tasks: 1
14/03/24 21:00:10 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/03/24 21:00:11 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201403241418_0001
.....
14/03/24 21:02:51 INFO driver.MahoutDriver: Program took 162906 ms (Minutes: 2.7151)
```

Following command fails ( using `/data/lda/output-seq2sparse` as input )

```
$ mahout seq2sparse -i /data/lda/output-seq2sparse -o /data/lda/output-seq2sparse-normalized -ow -a org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer -chunk 200 -wt tfidf -s 5 -md 3 -x 90 -ng 2  -ml 50 -seq -n 2 -nr 5
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/data/lda/output-seq2sparse/df-count/data
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:252)
    ....SKIPPED....
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

However this works just fine ( using `/data/lda/output-seqdir` as input )

```
$ mahout seq2sparse -i /data/lda/output-seqdir -o /data/lda/output-seq2sparse-normalized -ow -a org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer -chunk 200 -wt tfidf -s 5 -md 3 -x 90 -ng 2  -ml 50 -seq -n 2 -nr 5
Running on hadoop, using .../hadoop-1.1.1/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: ..../mahout-distribution-0.7/mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar
14/03/24 21:35:55 INFO vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles: Maximum n-gram size is: 2
14/03/24 21:35:56 INFO vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles: Minimum LLR value: 50.0
14/03/24 21:35:56 INFO vectorizer.SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles: Number of reduce tasks: 5
14/03/24 21:35:57 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
...SKIPPED...
14/03/24 21:45:11 INFO common.HadoopUtil: Deleting /data/lda/output-seq2sparse-normalized/partial-vectors-0
14/03/24 21:45:11 INFO driver.MahoutDriver: Program took 556420 ms (Minutes: 9.273666666666667)
```